# react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios

I can't find my error... Can anyone help me please?

```
const [testArtData, setTestArtData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getMyNfts = async () => {
    const openseaData = await axios.get(`https://testnets-api.opensea.io/assets?asset_contract_address=0x4Bef569089846759595C1ed598a3bD6D249FD7c4&order_direction=asc`);
    console.log(openseaData.data.assets);
    setTestArtData(openseaData.data.assets);
  }
  return getMyNfts()
}, [])
```

Everytime I get this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ro2.png)

You would help me so much! Thanks

Comment: `return getMyNfts()` This is returning a promise, and as the warning says, anything other than a function isn't expected. What's the purpose of this `return`?

Comment: You are returning the result of calling a function - `return getMyNfts()`, which is a promise and not a function. Call the function without the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to make a async function inside the useEffect itself and then call it underneath it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // wrap your async call here
    const loadData = async () => {
      setUsersLoading(true);
      const result = await getUsers();
      setUsers(result);
      setUsersLoading(false);
    };

    // then call it here
    loadData();
  }, []);
```

However, React does not recommend it because everything in useEffect is to be executed in a seprate thread and thus returned value may be needed by some other part of code and there is a chance of un-predictable behavior.